# Rails has_many through relationship for a user's debtors/creditors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, has-many-through

I am writing an app where a user can keep track of which users owe him money (his debtors) and which users he owes money to (his creditors).

This is my debt model:

```
class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :bill_id, :creditor_id, :debtor_id, :is_a_payment

  belongs_to :bill
  belongs_to :debtor,
    :class_name => "User",
    :foreign_key => :debtor_id

  belongs_to :creditor,
    :class_name => "User",
    :foreign_key => :creditor_id
end
```

This is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password, :username, :email

  has_many :debts,
    :foreign_key => "debtor_id"

  has_many :debtors,
    :through => :debts,
    :source => :user

  has_many :credits, 
    :class_name => "Debt",
    :foreign_key => "creditor_id"
end
```

Right now, I am able to get User.debts (Debts where his id = debtor_id) and User.credits (Debts where his id = creditor_id). I want to be able to find the User's debtors (find Debts where his id = creditor_id, and pull up all the debtor_ids of those debts) and the User's creditors (find Debts where his id = debtor_id, and pull up all the creditor_ids of those debts).

Answer (score 0):

In User class you should have two separate relationships

```
has_many :debts, :foreign_key => "debtor_id"
has_many :loans, :foreign_key => "creditor_id"
```

Comment: I have has_many :debts, :foreign_key => "debtor_id" and has_many :credits, :foreign_key => "creditor_id". But how can I pull up my debtors through debts? (That is, the users who owe me money)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You get debts with `user.debts` and debtors with `user.debtors`

Comment: When I got into rails console, I get an error trying to get user.debtors. Should it be in the user model   has_many :debtors,
    :through => :credits,
    :source => :debtor (right now I have :source => :user)

Comment: Yeah, probably. But you possibly may remove source at all.